# Is the representation of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in functions on Grassmannian multiplicity free?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, grassmannians

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a local non-Archimedean field. Let $\mathcal{O}\subset \mathbb{F}$ be its ring of integers. Let $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ be the (compact) group of $n\times n$ invertible matrices with entries in $\mathcal{O}$ such the inverse matrix also has entries in $\mathcal{O}$. Let $Gr_{i,n}$ be the Grassmannnian of linear $i$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{F}^n$.

> Is it true that the natural representation of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in the space of locally constant functions on $Gr_{i,n}$ is multiplicity free? In other words is it true that any irreducible representation of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ appears with multiplicity at most 1?

A reference would be helpful.

**Remark.** Archimedean analogue of the above statement, i.e. $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, is true; here $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ should be replaced by $O(n)$ or $U(n)$ respectively. (That follows from the fact that the Grassmannian is a symmetric space.)

Comment: Perhaps it would help to give some examples, e.g. what happens when $i=n-1$? Or for small $n$ such as $n=2$? A classification of irreducible representations of $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathcal O)$ seems to be known.

Comment: It is indeed known, see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870808002260

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is due to Hill:

*Hill, Gregory*, [**On the nilpotent representations of (GL_ n({\mathcal O}))**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02567703), Manuscr. Math. 82, No. 3-4, 293-311 (1994). See especially Corollary 3.2.

This was generalised and extended by Bader and Onn in

*Bader, Uri; Onn, Uri*, [**Geometric representations of (\text{GL}(n,R)), cellular Hecke algebras and the embedding problem.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2006.02.002), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 208, No. 3, 905-922 (2007).

and

*Bader, Uri; Onn, Uri*, [**On some geometric representations of (GL_N(\mathfrak{o}))**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927872.2011.561508), Commun. Algebra 40, No. 9, 3169-3191 (2012).

Answer (score 6):

This may be redundant as a complete answer with references has already been posted.
Just in case this is still useful: I think multiplicity one can be proved by the usual Gefland trick: we need to check that endomorphisms of the induced representation is a commutative ring, this follows once we check that the identity automorphism of that algebra is an anti-involution. The endomorphism algebra coincides with the Hecke algebra ${\mathbb{C}}[P(O)\backslash G(O)/P(O)]$ where $P$ is the group of block upper triangular matrices with blocks of sizes $i, \, n-i$. This can also be realized as the space of $G(O)$-invariant functions on pairs of rank $i$ summands in $O^n$. Switching the two elements in the pair induces an anti-involution. 
Looking at relative positions of two direct summands in $O^n$ one sees that the relative position of a pair $(N,M)$ is the same as the relative position of $(M,N)$, which yields the statement.