# Representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$ in functions on Grassmannians

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, grassmannians, p-adic

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a non-Archimedean local field. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be its ring of integers.
The natural representation of the group $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in the space of locally constant functions on the Grassmannian $\Gr_{i,n}$ of $i$-dimensional linear subspaces in $\mathbb{F}^n$ is known to be multiplicity free, see  the post [Is the representation of $GL_n(\mathcal{O})$ in functions on Grassmannian multiplicity free?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350230/is-the-representation-of-gl-n-mathcalo-in-functions-on-grassmannian-multip)

**Is it possible to give an explicit formula for a non-zero function on $\Gr_{i,n}$ in every irreducible $\GL_n(\mathcal{O})$-submodule?**

Furthermore let $P$ be the stabilizer of a certain fixed $i$-dimensional subspace, so that $\Gr_{i,n}=\GL_n(\mathcal{O})/P$. Then every irreducible subspace of functions on $\Gr_{i,n}$ contains a unique (up to a proportionality) $P$-invariant vector.

**Is it possible to describe this vector explicitly?**

Comment: Exhibit meaning give an explicit formula?

Comment: Regarding your second question: in general, I don't think this appears in the literature. For $i = 1$, this Grassmannian is projective space, in which case this is a special case of a result I recently proved. See my answer here, https://mathoverflow.net/a/383146/3803, and for more details Proposition 3.4 of my paper, https://doi.org/10.1007/s11856-023-2581-x.

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: To answer your questions, you'd probably need a parameterisation of the irreps of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$—do you have one?

Comment: @LSpice On p.2 of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405138.pdf   , Theorem 1, it is stated that there is such a parameterization of irreducible subrepresentations of the space of functions on Grassmannians , see references therein.

Comment: Theorem 1 of that paper does not answer the question of @LSpice. Rather, it explains that the Grassmann representation is multiplicity-free and gives a way of parametrising the irreducible representations that appear in this representation. It does *not* state that every irreducible representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$ arises as one of these representations, nor gives a way of parametrising representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries: to the second question, is the answer known for real Grassmannians?

Comment: @PeterHumphries, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/465947/representations-of-mathrmgl-n-mathcalo-in-functions-on-grassmannians#comment1208774_465947), it doesn't directly answer my question as asked, but it does answer my objection—if one is, as here, interested only in those representations of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathcal O)$ that appear in a Grassmannian, then it's fine to parameterise only those, and (for these purposes) simply to discard the others.

Comment: Hi. I believe the answers are essentially given in the following two papers,
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411461 and (in particular) https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404408.

Comment: @UriBader: Thank you. A more precise guide to your papers would be helpful. Do you mean my first or second question?

Comment: I meant both. I added an answer. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404408.pdf), by Uri Onn and myself.
It might not be very easy to read (I am sorry for this, but this paper and its [companion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411461.pdf) were the first ones each of us wrote and we were young and inexperience).

You are asking of an explicit description of the $P$-invariant vectors in the space of locally constant functions on $\text{Gr}_{i,n}=\text{GL}_n(\mathcal{O})/P$.
Each such locally constant function is actually invariant under a small enough congurence subgroup, so we may replace $\text{GL}_n(\mathcal{O})$ by its corresponding quotients. Below I fix an integer $k$, set $G= \text{GL}_n(\mathcal{O}/p^k)$ and by abuse of notation regard $P$ as its image in $G$. These are finite groups and the function spaces below are finite dimensional.

Let $V$ be the space of functions over $G/P$ and conisder the sub vector space of $P$-invariants, $H=V^P$, which we identify with the space of functions on $P\backslash G/P$. $H$ has a natural basis, given by $\delta$ functions (or characteristic functions of $P$-orbits on $G/P$, considered as elements in $V$). However, $H$ aslo has a natural (Hecke-)algebra structure, and what you are looking for really is the idempotents in this algebra, which form another basis for $H$.

What we give in the abovementioned [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404408.pdf) is the transition matrix between these two bases. In fact, we consider a third basis, which we call a cellular basis, and we give the transition matrices between each of the previous ones and this basis. The advantage of doing so is that these matrices are triangular, one is upper triangular and the other is lower triangular.

We give the matrices rather explicitly, using a combintaorial type formulation. The formulas we came with are actually based on many explicit compuation we made using a computer package that deals with q-series. Unfortunately, I do not remeber the deatils of these computations now (maybe Uri Onn does, and you could certainly email him and ask).

In reading the paper, my advice would be to start by considering the case $k=1$ (that is, to work over the residue field).
Then $P\backslash G/P$ is a set of size $i+1$ (assuming $i<n/2$, which does not reduce the generality, by an easy duality argument), which you may think as possible dimensions of a subspaces of an $i$-dim vector space.
After getting this, try $k=2$ and then you'll get a good feeling of what's going on.

Please let me know if it helps. If not, I can try to provide more explanations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your remarks. This is certainly relevant, although I would prefer a more direct description of spherical functions as a final answer.